# multi line Tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

i have the following button:

```
option1=tkinter.Button(opt1,text='this is a test to see how many words we can fit in a button and stuff so heres some more words',width=49,height=3,bg='grey',)
```

this makes a button which has the words `see how many words we can fit in a button and stuff so heres som`.

i want the text to move down to the next line instead of going off the side of the button.

also, how can i make it so the text is not centred?

python 3.3.3.

Comment: You could make two buttons, one above the other, with the same command, but different writing, this will appear to be one button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `wraplength` option is a good way to make it wrap, and the `justify` option to do something other than center:

```
option1 = tkinter.Button(opt1, wraplength=80, justify=LEFT, text='This is the text')
```

The value of `wraplength` is in screen units, or pixels. You can also just drop a `'\n'` character into the middle of your string to break the line manually, but may also have to size the button manually if you do this.